# Why shouldn’t you use DISTINCT when you could use GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, mysql

According to [tips](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Top10SQLPerformanceTips) from MySQL performance wiki:

> Don't use DISTINCT when you have or could use GROUP BY.

Can somebody post example of queries where GROUP BY can be used instead of DISTINCT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know that two columns from your result are always directly related then it's slower to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId, CustomerName FROM (...)
```

than this:

```
SELECT CustomerId, CustomerName FROM (...) GROUP BY CustomerId
```

because in the second case it only has to compare the id, but in the first case it has to compare both fields. This is a MySQL specific trick. It won't work with other databases.

Comment: Those two queries aren't the same, are they? In the second one you're only selecting distinct IDs, not distinct names as well.

Comment: This won't work with any other T-SQL, or it won't be faster with any other one?

Comment: Well the second one doesn't work!!! Any Column not included in the GROUP BY clause requires an aggregation function.

Comment: Craig Young: really? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html "MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that you can use nonaggregated columns or calculations in the SELECT list that do not appear in the GROUP BY clause." What version of MySQL are you using? Maybe you have turned this feature off? "This extension does not apply if the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled."

Comment: @Mark: Lets assume you have the following data for Col1, Col2 ungrouped: {1,First}{1,Second}; If you `select Col1, Col2 from (...) group by Col1` - Which of the 2 possible unaggregated values should be selected from Col2? The query is ambiguous, and as such should **NEVER** be allowed to work.

Comment: @CraigYoung: I think the key point is 'directly related' which means that it only works reliably when there is a functional dependency CustomerID ⟶ CustomerName, whereas your example by definition does not have the equivalent functional dependency.  In the absence of the functional dependency, you're correct.  AFAICT MySQL doesn't actually care (or know?) whether the functional dependency exists; it just assumes it does and pulls matching values for a given grouped-by column 'at random'.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Code
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Code
```

vs

```
SELECT DISTINCT Code
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: how is this an answer to the q? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule : Put all the columns from the SELECT clause into the GROUP BY clause

so

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM D
```

becomes

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM D GROUP BY a,b,c
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong.  Shouldn't the basic rule be, put all non-aggregate columns from the SELECT clause in the GROUP BY clause?

Answer (score -2):

Example.

Relation customer(ssnum,name, zipcode, address) PK(ssnum). ssnum is social security number.

SQL:

```
 Select DISTINCT ssnum from customer where zipcode=1234 group by name
```

This SQL statement returns unique records for those customer's that have zipcode 1234. At the end results are grouped by name.

Here DISTINCT is no not necessary. because you are selecting ssnum which is already unique because ssnun is primary key. two person can not have same ssnum.

In this case `Select ssnum from customer where zipcode=1234 group by name` will give better performance than "... DISTINCT.......".

DISTINCT is an expensive operation in a DBMS.

Comment: What is the difference in the answer when you have GROUP BY and no GROUP BY?  What is the difference in the answer when you have DISTINCT and no DISTINCT (is that 'indistinct'?)?  AFAICS, the queries would all yield the same result set (give or take ordering, which doesn't count), though not necessarily all at the same speed.