# Programatically remove duplicates on database field

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, distinct, duplicates

I have the query properly outputting on the database end, but my php is not showing each distinct group name based on education_id

This is now fixed. The issue was with a selector in my database selection, when used in my php function.

Comment: you want to eliminate duplicates with query or after query execution?

Comment: if you want to do this in query, group by the duplicate filled column. if you want to eliminate them after query execution, use a PHP built in function :D

Comment: After query execution

Comment: I need to do it on "display" of the records. Please see the code abov

Comment: then use array_unique() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php array_unique — Removes duplicate values from an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna do this in MySQL, you can use [*"Distinct"*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) or [*"Group by"*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) in your query. (Recommended)

And for ordering you can use [*"Order by"*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)

But if you wanna do this in PHP, you can use [*"array_unique"*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Comment: Please see the updated query above. I need to order by [order] column, but also groupby the [GroupName] - how can I achieve this?

Comment: Mysql, see updated query above and the image of what the query outputs

Comment: you need to use ORDER BY `order` at the end of your query

Comment: I updated my query, now it isnt outputting the values based on education level

Comment: Please see the updated issue and code provided above

Comment: I think you cant use DISTINCT and ORDER BY together. see this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887953/why-shouldn-t-you-use-distinct-when-you-could-use-group-by

Comment: It works fine against my database to give desired output. I just need some help to output this properly with php based on education_id

Comment: Take that back, I had a erroneous database attribute selection in my db call that wasn't syncing up with the php output - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you should use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) - Removes duplicate values from an array

like so:

```
.
.
.
    $qresults = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qresults)) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }

    $results = array_unique($results);
    return $results;
}
```

if you want to get rid of the elements in the array that have numbers as keys and just keep the ones with string as keys, just use this:

```
foreach($array as $key1=>$arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key3=>$value) {
        if(is_numeric($key)) {
            unset($array[$key1][$key3]);
        }
    }
}
```

this will show up like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Pathway_ID] => 54
            [Master_ID] => 6
            [Group_ID] => 26
            [Job_Outlook] => in demand
            [type] => Education
            [Ed_Name] => High School Diploma or GED
            [Education_ID] => 4
            [Career_Name] => Industrial Production Managers - Maintenance
            [Order #] => 2
            [GroupName] => Facility Maintenance Workers
            [EntryWage] => 9.71-11.96
            [MedianWage] => 18.30-21.56
            [Job_Title] => Installation, Maintenance, and Repair Workers, All Other
        )

)
```

assuming that `$array` is an array like the one provided in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work, it is not displaying the right records now

Comment: how does your array look like? update your question with a minimal result from DB so I can test it more and provide a better answer ;)

Comment: Added array above. For example. "Facility Maintenance Worker" is showing twice

Comment: everything is showing twice :) you want just the array with description strings like: `[Career_Name] => Industrial Production Managers - Maintenance`?

Comment: I also added an image of what this is looking like on the output

Comment: See how it is under the "Post Secondary Certificate" with unique positions under each, but on the "Associates Degree" it has 1 job that is repeating - I just want to have it like the  "Post Secondary Certificate" has unique  job per blue section

Comment: It looks like for the array_unique function, I need to be using the http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php as the [GroupName] field is a string

Comment: Can you help with the above issue?